# Java - default interface method cannot act as implementation for other interface method

Tags: java, java-8, interface

Could someone point me out the reason why default interface methods cannot define behavior/implementation for other interface methods implemented by a certain class, please?

```
interface Transformable {
    int quarter();
    BigDecimal value();
}

interface Quarterly {

    int getQuarter();

    void setQuarter(int quarter);

    // Method that I would expect to be used to define Transformable method behavior
    default int quarter() {
        return getQuarter();
    }
}

// expects quarter() implementation
static class SomethingQuarterly implements Quarterly, Transformable {

    private int quarter;
    private BigDecimal value;

    @Override
    public int getQuarter() {
        return quarter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuarter(int quarter) {
        this.quarter = quarter;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if `Transformable::quarter` were to change to a default method, which should be a backwards compatible change from the interface's perspective, it would cause [the diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Which of the two defaults would get chosen?

The compiler doesn't know, of course, and so the safest thing is to make the person writing the implementation resolve the problem *even though* the problem doesn't exist yet. By making the implementer resolve the ambiguity, `Transformable::quarter` can change to a default method in the future without breaking `SomethingQuarterly`.

If the two methods are conceptually related and `Quarterly` should override `Transformable`, you should make `Quarterly` extend that interface.

```
interface Quarterly extends Transformable {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ok @Michael, I think you clarified it when you pointed out the backward compatibility. A possible Transformable::quarter default later implementation would break the 'clients'.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, your Quarterly interface has to inherit from the Transformable interface. Thus, do the following modification:

```
interface Quarterly extends Transformable {

    int getQuarter();

    void setQuarter(int quarter);

    // Method that I would expect to be used to define Transformable method behavior
    default int quarter() {
        return getQuarter();
    }
}
```

After this, your `SomethingQuarterly` class can implement just the Quarterly interface.

Comment: As @Michael stated, it is only a solution in case you have a conceptual relation between interfaces. That's not the case. Thanks anyway.